# How to show expected error as pass in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, assertion

Response message in View results in a tree is "xyz abc".

We would like to accept this error as pass. I tried "Ignore status" check but that doesnot work in assertion.

Comment: question isn't clear, show test plan, response and assertion(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMeter automatically treats [Response Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) >= 400 as not successful. `Ignore Status` box of the [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) should suppress this check.

If you want JMeter to mark Sampler with **Response Messagexyz abc` as successful you can add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of this Sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
if (prev.getResponseMessage().equals('xyz abc')) {
    prev.setSuccessful(true)
}
```

Check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article for more information on defining custom pass/fail criteria using Groovy language